# Coinbase API: How to get market or spot prices for all currencies

Tags: coinbase-api

The current Coinbase API for market data: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price only provides the spot price for one currency per API call. Is there a supported API that can provide the SPOT or market price for all supported currencies in a single API call?

Comment: Not every crypto is traded in all fiat currencies. I guess most of them are traded against the USD. Then figure out the exchange rate between USD vs desired currency.

Comment: Were you ever able to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Like @Andy answer, use `.../v2/exchange-rates?currency=CURRENCY` (replace CURRENCY by any currency available one Coinbase.

For instance do a query to `.../v2/exchange-rates?currency=USD` and to get the prices against USD divide 1 by the exchange rate given.

So if you get:

```
...
    "currency":"USD",
          "rates":{
             "BTC":"2.8266877198368038e-05",
             "ETH":"0.00041082102582010144",
             ...
          }
...
```

To get ETH price against USD, you can do 1/0.00041082102582010144 = 2434,15 USD.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "/v2/exchange-rates?currency={0}" with for example "USD" as the currency, and it will return all other currencies' exchange rate for USD.