# Coinbase API: Get spot prices for multiple assets

Tags: coinbase-api

This question is very [similar to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67498789/coinbase-api-how-to-get-market-or-spot-prices-for-all-currencies) which received no answer. Using the Coinbase public API, it's possible to get the spot price of an asset [via this endpoint](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#get-spot-price).

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BCH-USD/spot
```

If I'm building an application that needs to watch the spot prices of 10 different markets, am I supposed to make 10 calls?  Is there a way to submit the list of markets I want the spot price for?

As a backup, as the linked question above asks, is there a way to get all supported spot prices in one call so I can filter out what I want?  It's still really inefficient, but probably not as bad as making 10 calls.